# How do I change the parent class instance/attributes of a class object in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, subclass

I've used Python successfully for batch scripting with Excel for a few months, if not longer, but I still haven't really understood object-oriented programming.

Let's say I have the following code, except there are many more people/families (let's say, 50 families) and many more family attributes than just last name, address, and family size (let's say, 10 attributes).

```
class Family():
    def __init__(self, family_id, last_name, address, family_size):  
        self.family_id = family_id  
        self.last_name = last_name  
        self.address = address
        self.family_size = family_size  

class Person(Family):
    def __init___(self, family_id, last_name, address, family_size, person_id, first_name,  
                  middle_name):
        super().__init__(id, last_name, address, family_size)
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name

jones1 = Family(2, "Jones", "456 Main Street", 1)
bob1 = Person(1, "Smith", "123 Main Street", 1, 1, "Bob", "James")    
alice1 = Person(2, "Jones", "456 Main Street", 1, 2, "Alice", "Mary")
```

Now let's say I've instantiated two objects (people) named Bob and Alice. They are from two different families. However, let's say I want Bob and Alice to marry, which means that one of them abandons their own family and joins the family of the other.

How do I do this, code-wise? I know I can type:

```
 bob1.last_name = "Jones"
```

And now Bob has Alice's last name. But there must be easier ways than manually overwriting each class attribute. I feel like I'm missing something very simple regarding the family object (jones1), but how do I get Bob to be part of the Jones family?

EDIT: To clarify in response to the downvotes, this is an exercise and not directly related to what I'm working on. I'm new to understanding OOP and to Stack Overflow; if you have any comments about how I could word my question better, besides posting with less actual code errors, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: `class Person(Family)` isn't a sensible subclass relationship - it implies that a person *is* a family. You need composition, not subclassing.

Comment: Also, even ignoring the `"` typo, this code won't run, and it's not clear how it's _supposed_ to work. Your `Person.__init__` doesn't have any of those variables that it's trying to pass to `super().__init__`, and then it tries to use `id`, which it also doesn't have as a variable. And then, for good measure, you call the constructors with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: I came up with the code on the fly as a simplified, theoretical example of what I'm actually working with; I haven't tried running it. I was looking for more theoretical directions towards the right way to implement members of a family with OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have some suggestions for your code.

- It's better to use new style class that inherits from object `class Foo(object)`.
- For new style class, use `super(ChildClass, self).__init__()` to override init method.
- Family should not be the base class but another class which a Person belongs to. Meaning of base class is that the child class is a sub type of the base class. Obviously, person is not a sub type of family. We can say dog is a sub type of animal.

I made some adjust to your code. You may need to modify as your own thinking.

```
class Family(object):
    def __init__(self, family_id, last_name, address, family_size):  
        self.family_id = family_id  
        self.last_name = last_name  
        self.address = address
        self.family_size = family_size  

class Person(object):
    def __init___(self, family_id, last_name, address, family_size, person_id, first_name,  
              middle_name):
        self.id = ...
        self.last_name = ...
        ...
        self.person_id = person_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name

    def join_family(self, new_family):
        self.family.family_size -= 1
        self.family = new_family
        new_family.family_size += 1

    def marry_to(self, person):
        self.join_family(person.family)

family_smith = Family(1, "Smith", "789 Main Street", 1)
family_jones1 = Family(2, "Jones", "456 Main Street", 1)
bob1 = Person(1, "Smith", "123 Main Street", 1, 1, "Bob", "James")    
alice1 = Person(2, "Jones", "456 Main Street", 1, 2, "Alice", "Mary")
```

Then Bob married and joined Alice's family

```
bob1.marry_to(alice1)
```

or

```
bob1.join_family(family_jones1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is a *is a* relation. A person is not a family but belongs to a family so inheritance here is suspect.

Two different persons can belong to the same family, which cannot be achieved with inheritance => you need a 1-n parent-child type relation. A common way is to include a container (for example a set or a list) in family, and/or a reference to family in person:

```
class Family:
    def __init__(self, id, last_name, address):  
        self.id = id  
        self.last_name = last_name  
        self.address = address
        self.family_members = set()
    def add(self, member):
        member.family = self
        self.family_members.add(member)
    def remove(self, member):
        member.family = self
        self.family_members.remove(member)

class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name, middle_name, family):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        family.add(self)
    def change_family(self, new_family):
        self.family.remove(self)
        new_family.add(self)
```

I have added the `change_family` method to person which is what you need for Alice to marry Bob...

---

The classic inheritance example is Animal, Cat and Dog. A cat *is* an animal (and a dog is too) and 2 different cats are different animals...

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation. Is remove(self) a method I'd have to create myself, like family.add(self), or is it built-in, like list.remove(item)?

Comment: @Strangely: It is a method I had forgotten to write here :-)